# is openstack swift required for juju integration?

Tags: juju

For juju integration with openstack, is swift object store a requirement?

I have a private setup with nova-compute, nova-network, keystone and glance. But don't have swift. Exact question had been asked previously, but it's not clear if integration is possible without swift.

[Is Swift object storage a requirement?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173342/is-swift-object-storage-a-requirement)

Comment: I've tacked on a bounty to the original to get it updated!